AWS Amplify CLI update private policy for S3 policyUUID
I have a private policy generated by Amplify CLI for S3 that allows Put and Get for /private/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/* for a signed in Cognito User Pool user. Great. Now I need those signed in users to also be able to access /public/* files. I updated my policy in IAM -> Roles:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::project-dev/private/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::project-dev/public/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}

Locally, I ran amplify cli command amplify pull but it didn't pull down the policy changes. How can I get my local config in sync including cloud formation settings?? When I check the local project amplify/storage/projectName/build/cloudformation-template.json it does not have the updated public access. I tried to add it manually but it just gets removed during a push or pull.
